# Could not get GDAL suggested warp output for output dataset creation

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, gdalwarp

I am not sure what this message means?

It happens while trying to perform St_Transform on a raster dataset using the following...

```
SELECT
rid,
ST_Transform(rast,2275) as rast
INTO nlcd_2011_2275
FROM
public.nlcd_2011_nad83
LIMIT 1;
```

The error message says exactly this...

```
ERROR: rt_raster_gdal_warp: Could not get GDAL suggested warp output for output dataset creation
SQL state: XX000
Context: SQL function "st_transform" statement 1
```

My table in question was created as follows...

```
CREATE TABLE public.nlcd_2011_nad83
(
  rid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('nlcd_2011_nad83_rid_seq'::regclass),
  rast raster,
  CONSTRAINT nlcd_2011_nad83_pkey PRIMARY KEY (rid),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_height_rast CHECK (st_height(rast) = 52),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_max_extent_rast CHECK (st_envelope(rast) @ '0103000020AD1000000100000005000000FBF8FD68DB002DC1FF7CF0504CEE2A41FBF8FD68DB002DC1DCD9A6946BC53B41535996AF38F204C1DCD9A6946BC53B41535996AF38F204C1FF7CF0504CEE2A41FBF8FD68DB002DC1FF7CF0504CEE2A41'::geometry),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_nodata_values_rast CHECK (_raster_constraint_nodata_values(rast) = '{0.0000000000}'::numeric[]),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_num_bands_rast CHECK (st_numbands(rast) = 1),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_out_db_rast CHECK (_raster_constraint_out_db(rast) = '{f}'::boolean[]),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_pixel_types_rast CHECK (_raster_constraint_pixel_types(rast) = '{8BUI}'::text[]),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_same_alignment_rast CHECK (st_samealignment(rast, '0100000000C90B8951E8FF3D401A15F70AD9FF3DC03E0A25CE041A21C14A5898B8CA45364100000000000000000000000000000000AD10000001000100'::raster)),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_scalex_rast CHECK (round(st_scalex(rast)::numeric, 10) = round(29.9996386489472, 10)),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_scaley_rast CHECK (round(st_scaley(rast)::numeric, 10) = round(- 29.9994055608014, 10)),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_rast CHECK (st_srid(rast) = 4269),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_width_rast CHECK (st_width(rast) = 40)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.nlcd_2011_nad83
  OWNER TO jcfcqrso;

-- Index: public.nlcd_2011_nad83_rast_gist

-- DROP INDEX public.nlcd_2011_nad83_rast_gist;

CREATE INDEX nlcd_2011_nad83_rast_gist
  ON public.nlcd_2011_nad83
  USING gist
  (st_convexhull(rast));
```

I am fairly new to to postgis and could not find any reference to this error while scouring the web.